# Can't, show Json response in Android app

Tags: android, json, jackson, response, resttemplate

Hello why can't I show my json response from this server? 
First example working : 
REPRESENTATIONAL CLASS :

```
package com.rest.jasjah.twojaaura.com.rest.jasjah.twojaaura.pojo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "one",
    "key"
})
public class ExampleOneTwo {

@JsonProperty("one")
private String one;
@JsonProperty("key")
private String key;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The one
 */
@JsonProperty("one")
public String getOne() {
    return one;
}

/**
 *
 * @param one
 * The one
 */
@JsonProperty("one")
public void setOne(String one) {
    this.one = one;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The key
 */
@JsonProperty("key")
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

/**
 *
 * @param key
 * The key
 */
@JsonProperty("key")
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

ACTIVITY METHOD  :

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ExampleOneTwo> {

    @Override
    protected ExampleOneTwo doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            final String url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            ExampleOneTwo exampleOneTwo = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ExampleOneTwo.class);
            return exampleOneTwo;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fields", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ExampleOneTwo exampleOneTwo) {

        TextView fieldTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGetTemp);
        TextView fieldWeather = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGetWeather);
        fieldTemp.setText(exampleOneTwo.getKey());
        fieldWeather.setText(exampleOneTwo.getOne());



    }
}
```

And this is working fine ... but now I try this on other server and it only shows empty fields in app.

REPRESENTATIONAL CLASS :

```
package com.rest.jasjah.twojaaura.com.rest.jasjah.twojaaura.pojo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

public class Value {

@JsonProperty("id")
private Integer id;
@JsonProperty("quote")
private String quote;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The id
 */
@JsonProperty("id")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 * The id
 */
@JsonProperty("id")
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The quote
 */
@JsonProperty("quote")
public String getQuote() {
    return quote;
}

/**
 *
 * @param quote
 * The quote
 */
@JsonProperty("quote")
public void setQuote(String quote) {
    this.quote = quote;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

ACTIVITY METHOD , is the same but I only changed variables, and url :

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Value> {

    @Override
    protected Value doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            final String url = "http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Value value = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Value.class);
            return value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fields", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Value value) {

        TextView fieldTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGetTemp);
        TextView fieldWeather = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGetWeather);
        fieldTemp.setText(value.getId().toString());
        fieldWeather.setText(value.getQuote());



    }
}
```

And now I see no response from the server, app calling well and get method I think, but on screen I have empty fields... Please help anyone?
 Greetings

Comment: please post response from both urls..

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means that your representational class does not exactly match the structure of the JSON response. First make sure the server is returning valid JSON, next, make sure the representational class has all the correct field names with capitalisation as appropriate

Comment: I understand , thank you. But i tryied a lot of combinations with this response fields in POJO. Maybe , this is wrong Jacskon  annotation's fault? ( Property , ignore ) ?

Comment: Perhaps post the json your attempting to retreive

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it... 
If you need to have permission to deeper fields you need to call method from upper class.
Like this :

public class ValueMain {

```
@JsonProperty("type")
private String type;
@JsonProperty("value")
private Value value;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String,   Object>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The type
 */
@JsonProperty("type")
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

/**
 *
 * @param type
 * The type
 */
@JsonProperty("type")
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The value
 */
@JsonProperty("value")
public Value getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 *
 * @param value
 * The value
 */
@JsonProperty("value")
public void setValue(Value value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

And now I call method in activity :

```
fieldTemp.setText(valueMain.getValue().getQuote());
```